# use graphql query and mutation in same file

Tags: reactjs, graphql

```
    const QUERIES = gql`
    query {
    getGrades {
        grade_info
        id
    }

    getSubjects {
        id
        subject_info
    }

    getSchools {
        school_name
        id
    }
    }
    `;

    const MUTATIONS = gql`
    mutation {
        createTeacher(
        first_name: ${firstName}
        last_name: ${lastName}
        phone: "${number}
        email: ${email}
        subjectRef: ["6287323efe0b204eee241cc5"]
        gradeRef: ["62872b8b0023e0dcc9c5a703"]
        schoolRef: "62ab59edde044d104f10e5a9"
        ) {
        id
        first_name
        last_name
        phone
        email
        email_verified
        approved
        number_verified
        }
    }
    `;

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERIES);
    const [mutateFunction, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(MUTATIONS);
```

Here is my graphql query using in react .
But my data variable conflicting in query and mutation

How to handle the situation ?

Please take a look .

If am changing data to something else it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a destructuring assignment in order to extract the fields `data, error, loading` from the response of useQuery and useMutation.
The destructuring assingment operator allows renaming the variables (please find better variable names than I used as an example ;-) )

Example:

```
const { loading: loadingQueries, error: errorQueries, data: dataQueries } = useQuery(QUERIES);

//use
console.log(loadingQueries);
```

The same can be applied for useMutation.

Comment: How can i use data now to show in UI ?

Comment: You would need to use dataQueries in the queries case and data in the useMutation (unless also renamed during destructuring).